# How do i change the value of an object from an inner method?

Tags: java

I need to change the value of `newiconid[0]` to `arg2` from method `onItemSelected()`. And I need to use that value in `onClick()`. The following code does not work, it just keeps the value of `newiconid[0]` as `0`. How to accomplish this?

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
        int which) {
    final int newiconid[] = new int[1];
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(
                AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("" + arg1 + arg2
                    + arg3);
            newiconid[0] = arg2;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(
                AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("updateicon "+newiconid[0]+" "+itemid);
    datasource.updateVSIcon(newiconid[0], itemid);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try making `newiconid` a class member instead? It should then be accessible in both scopes. And yes, as @Agent404 said, do not make it `final`

Comment: That worked, how come class members can be accessed and changed from inner methods?

Comment: That is the whole point of inner classes.  They have a special relationship with their enclosing class.

Comment: @BinoyBabu I *think* the reason is - because it's an *inner method*; something that can be invoked without invoking the outer method. Thus it would have to have accessible scope without relying on one another. Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @BinoyBabu By declaring a variable in a method, you're declaring it on the stack and not on the heap. The stack frame goes away when the method finishes execution. In this case, the inner method's variable will occlude the outer method's variable so long as it's on the stack. Once it's off the stack, the original value will reassert itself. By declaring the variable as part of the object, it is stored on the heap. Any change to it will persist across all calls to that instantiation on the heap.

Answer (score 2):

You've made it a **FINAL**, Final's are constants and DO NOT CHANGE once they've be initialized. Try taking final out first and Let us know what happens.

Comment: code won't compile if final is removed, `Cannot refer to a non-final variable newiconid inside an inner class defined in a different method`

Comment: just keep  newiconid[]  as class attribute. This will get you rid of the final keyword

Comment: As stated by Eric R. Keep it in the actual class and then you can remove final without a compilation error.

Comment: This is not entirely true. A variable defined as final will point to a particular place in memory. That place in memory cannot change. Therefore, one could not instantiate and assign an entirely new object to a final variable. BUT, the components of that variable CAN change. In this case, once he's initialized newiconid, he won't be able to change the length of that array... but he can modify the contents to his heart's desire.